# Coffeescript not working in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to get a function into the asset pipeline in coffeescript

If I use pure javascript,

mymodel.js

```
function restrictPlayback(event) {
   // Trying to stop the player if it goes above 1 second
   if (event.currentTime > 10) {
     event.pause();
     event.currentTime = 0
   }
 }
```

This compiles fine and the function works.

If I put the following:

mymodel.js.coffee

```
restrictPlayback = (event) ->

  # Trying to stop the player if it goes above 10 seconds
  if event.currentTime > 10
    event.pause()
    event.currentTime = 0
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: restrictPlayback is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't write Coffeescript but I put your JS into [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/) and it has a return statement at the end of the function. It also depends on where you're trying to access `restrictPlayback`.

Comment: The issue is not related to the code you gave us.  Your CoffeeScript compiles fine.

Comment: Where are you calling `restrictPlayback`? If it's before you declare it, that's likely what the issue is

Comment: I'm trying to put it in the asset pipeline. 
If I put recordings.js as a file, this merges into application.js fine. If I put it as recordings.js.coffee as a coffeescript file, it doesn't work anymore. 
Possibly the issue is that my application.js is exactly that. application.js, not application.js.coffee...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're defining the function and then expecting it to have global scope (i.e. usable from anywhere).

By default, Coffeescript wraps compiled code into [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so the function you declared is only valid within the scope of the Coffeescript file.

You can get Coffeescript to stop wrapping in IIFEs by using the -b flag when compiling although it's much better practice to learn to do things the Coffeescript way.